# call to udefined function form_open()?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpstorm

My problem is that I am getting errors on CI's common function. I have done everything like:

```
 $autoload['helpers'] = array('form','myhelper');
```

Previously I am using Dreamweaver and not getting those messages there, now I have to work upon PhpStorm.

This is my default controller:

```
      $this->load->helper('url');
      $this->load->view('header');
      $this->load->view('home');
      $this->load->helper('form');
      $this->load->view('footer');
```

I have also used this [tutorial](http://validwebs.com/346/code-completion-for-codeigniter-in-phpstorm/), but no success.

[image]
[image]

These were the errors what i used to get!

Comment: Did you execute this php script itself or calling the whole index of codeigniter and access it via routes?

Comment: access it via routes

Comment: OK then running from browser or phpstorm?

Comment: when i right click on  my default controller script and then click on run...
i get Class 'CI_Controller' not found

Comment: is this error happening when you run the application on your browser or is the error a PHPStorm error? can you provide more details of this error? perhaps a screen shot? If it is a PHPStorm issue, then you need to make sure you have the right files set for Code Completion in PHPStorm for Codeigniter. All you would have to do is update any classes for CI version 3.

Comment: Load helper before loading view files. Put `form` line before `header` line.

Comment: i have updated the question with screen shot ...

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget exteding `CI_Controller` like following:

**application/controllers/Homepage.php**

```
class Homepage extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```